# Wrapper array is showing as blank in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a wrapper class sending data to my Arua component. we have confirmed the Data is populated on the apex side but when sending to the aura component it displays as blank. Code below:

Apex:

```
public without sharing class CarouselController {
    
    public class SlideWrapper{
        @auraenabled
        Carousel_Slide__c slide {get;set;}
        @auraenabled
        ContentDocumentLink cdl {get;set;}
    }
    
    @auraenabled
    public static List<SlideWrapper> getSlides(){
        List<Carousel_Slide__c> slides = [SELECT ID, Description__c, Heading__c, Active__c, Link__c, Image_Assistive_Text__c, Carousel_Slide_Order__c FROM Carousel_Slide__c WHERE Active__c = true ORDER BY Carousel_Slide_Order__c asc];
        List<SlideWrapper> slideWrappers = new List<SlideWrapper>();
        for(Carousel_Slide__c cs : slides){
            SlideWrapper sW = new SlideWrapper();
            sW.slide = cs;
            List<ContentDocumentLink> img = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId  FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId in ( SELECT Id FROM Carousel_Slide__c where id = :cs.id ) and LinkedEntity.Type='Carousel_Slide__c' ];
            system.debug(img);
            sW.cdl = (img.size() > 0) ? img[0] : null;
            slideWrappers.add(sW);
        }
        system.debug(slideWrappers);
        return slideWrappers;
    }
}
```

Aura controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.img', "{!$Resource.goldenratio}");
        var action = component.get("c.getSlides");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var slides = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('Response: ' + slides);
                console.log(slides);
                console.log(slides[1]);
                component.set("v.slides", slides);
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                
                Console.log("didnt work");
                // do something
            }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                            console.log("Error message: " + 
                                        errors[0].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown error");
                    }
                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    }
})
```

Aura component:

```
<aura:component controller="CarouselController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="img" type="string"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="slides" type="List"/>

    <lightning:carousel disableAutoScroll="false" scrollDuration="5">
        <aura:iteration var="wrapper" items="{!v.slides}" indexVar="i">
            <lightning:carouselImage
                                     src = "{!'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + wrapper.cdl.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId}"
                                     href = "{!wrapper.slide.Link__c}"
                                     alternativeText = "{!wrapper.slide.Image_Assistive_Text__c}"></lightning:carouselImage>
        </aura:iteration>
        
   </lightning:carousel>
</aura:component>
```

In the console log the array is showing as these blank values:

[image: Carousel error]

Comment: what blank value? line 18 seems to indicate an array of objects.

Comment: Try instead logging `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(slides[1]))`.

Comment: @glls It does say there is an array of objects but the data does not seem to be making it. so the array has the correct amount of objects (4) but the values that are supposed be present dont seem to be.

Comment: Your two properties (`slide` and `cdl`) in the `SlideWrapper` class are not marked as `public` which is likely the culprit here in the serializer's behavior omitting them. Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/169316/660

Comment: @MarkPond That was it! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Your two properties (slide and cdl) in the SlideWrapper class are not marked as public which is likely the culprit here in the serializer's behavior omitting them. Related: salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/169316/660 – Mark Pond 2 mins ago